# Read the excel file from the SharePoint online site and insert the excel data to the Azure SQL DB

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

I am working with the accessing the excel document from SharePoint online document library and read the excel file insert that data into the Azure SQL DB.

In this i have create the Azure Web API and accessing the SharePoint online site from the this Azure Web API. I am having issue in reading the excel file from the SharePoint online Document Library. If any one has done this before please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.